# How would I print a whole column based upon string. (Random Column Number)

Tags: string, awk, grep, cut

On day one I may receive large CSV output such as:

`this,is,a,test

bob,is,your,uncle

sound,one,"Zen proverb",clapping`



On day two I may receive output such as:


`test,this,is,a

clapping,one,sound,"Zen proverb"

uncle,bob,is,your

Neo,the,Matrix,"Has you"`



The column and row I'm interested in will always be random, I'll never know which field the output will come to me as - but I'm only interested in the vertical column with a certain string. For example 'Uncle'.

`test

clapping

uncle

Neo`

I'm a newbie to awk and PERL - but I imagine awk would be able to print the first match column based upon a matched string (Up-and-Down the column). Does anyone know how I should go about parsing this kind of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the following: given a string and a comma separated file, find the first match of the string and output that field for each record in the file.  Make 2 passes on the file, with the first pass looking for the match:

```
 s=uncle
 awk 'NR==FNR && /'$s'/ { for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) if( $i ~ /'$s'/ ) { a=i; nextfile; } }
    NR!=FNR{ print $a}' FS=, input input
```

Note that if the string is not in the file, the second pass will print the whole record.  Also `nextfile` is not standard awk, but does exist in `gawk`.  Rather than `nextfile`, you can do: `NR==FNR && /'$s'/ && !a`, or just invoke awk twice, with the first just getting the column to output and the 2nd doing the printing.